# php function parameter is not retaining full string passed in

Tags: php, function-parameter, texttrimming

I have a PHP function that in echoing out a string, is losing some of the characters passed in it. Any reason why this would be happening?

I pass: `$vhkvdov#jqlydk#p*_L#1qrlws|ufqh#KWLZ#1hwdgsX`

It returns: `#jqlydk#p*_L#1qrlws|ufqh#KWLZ#1hwdgsX`

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
function display($str) {
    echo $str;
}
display("$vhkvdov#jqlydk#p*_L#1qrlws|ufqh#KWLZ#1hwdgsX");
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `$` in you string use single quotes:

```
display('$vhkvdov#jqlydk#p*_L#1qrlws|ufqh#KWLZ#1hwdgsX');
```

Otherwise PHP would try to use `$vhkvdov` as a variable name and replace it by its contents, what will be nothing as I expect that the variable is not set

[PHP reference on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

---

**Note**: During development I would set `error_reporting` in php.ini to

```
error_reporting=E_ALL | E_NOTICE;
```

and

```
display_errors=On
```

or

```
log_errors=On
error_log=PATH/TO/YOUR/LOG.file ; make sure this is writable by the web server
```

To **see** an error message like :

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: vhkvdov in

Comment: Activating notices in PHP while development can help debugging such issues as it would return something like "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: vhkvdov in file.php on line XX"

Comment: oh yeahhhh....that totally just slipped my mind. too long at the computer haha. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using **double quotes**, which make PHP interpret the inner string for PHP variables.

Consider the following example:

```
$friend = "foo";
echo "hello $friend";
// Output: hello foo
```

Use **single quotes** instead if you do not want PHP to interpret the string contents.

```
$friend = "foo";
echo 'hello $friend';
// Output: hello $friend
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a read of this to help clarify why this is happening:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Specifically:

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
>   are parsed within it.

This is whats happening with your code:

> If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as
>   many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. Enclose the
>   variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the
>   name.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$juice = "apple";

echo "He drank some $juice juice.".PHP_EOL;
// Invalid. "s" is a valid character for a variable name, but the variable is $juice.
echo "He drank some juice made of $juices.";
?>
```

The above example will output:

> He drank some apple juice.
>
> He drank some juice made of .

When you use single quotes, you will avoid this issue as the string taken litterally:

```
// Outputs: This will not expand: \n a newline
echo 'This will not expand: \n a newline';

// Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
```

Comment: Rather than just posting a link, you should quote or explain the specific part you mean.